# The line through the center of circle $x^2+y^2-2ax=0$ and parallel to $x+2y=0$ meets the circle at $A$ and $B$. Find the area of $\triangle AOB$.

Tags: geometry

> A straight line is drawn through the centre of the circle $x^2+y^2-2ax=0$, parallel to straight line $x+2y=0$ and intersecting the circle at $A$ and $B$. Then what is the area of $\triangle AOB$?

I know that I am supposed to use the equation for center of the circle and then joining the centre with the origin or something like that. But I am unable to get answer through this. Please help.

Comment: Does the straight line going through the centre intersect the circle at A and B?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Isolated problem statements are discouraged here. Please always try to include (as you did in a previous question) your thoughts on a problem and some idea of where you got stuck. This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best help you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know, duplicating your effort, or using techniques with which you aren't familiar. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. :)

Comment: @Blue But i have no idea who to proceed in this question and that is the reason i did not include my thoughts.

Comment: @IshanDeo Probably yes.

Comment: @AdityaJain: Okay ... Let's be specific: (1) Do you know how to find the center of the given circle? (2) Do you know how to find the slope of the given line? (3) Do you know the relationship between the slopes of parallel lines? (4) Do you know how to find the equation of a line through a particular point and with a particular slope? (5) From the equation of a line and a circle, do you know how to find the points of intersection? (6) Given the coordinates of the vertices of a triangle, do you know how to find its area?

Comment: @Blue I don't know how to find out the centre of a circle and points of intersection from the equation of circle. I know the rest of the things.

Comment: @AdityaJain: That's more than having "no idea". :)  Do you know what the center of the circle $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$ is? If so, can you manipulate the given circle equation into that form? (Hint: Completing the square.)

Comment: I don't know about the centre of the circle but I know the method of completing the square. I think I will wait for a few days as one or two classes are  still left for this topic in my school and it might be covered in that. BTW thanks for help.

Comment: @Blue I was taught this topic in yesterday's class and teacher specifically discussed this question. Now i know about the center of and how to find the intersection. I can now solve this question. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Why has it been put on hold??

Comment: @AdityaJain: Congratulations! ... for being able to solve the problem, not for being put on hold. :)  ... The question was probably put on hold because of what I wrote above: isolated problem statements are discouraged. That said, I thought your comments showed you to be actively engaged in trying to understand the problem, but that had a little more to learn. People don't always check comments before down-voting. Anyway ... If you want more answers, you can improve the question so that it might get reopened. If you're satisfied with the accepted answer, however, then it really doesn't matter.

Comment: I think I am satisfied with the answer. But still I will try editing it. BTW thanks for your help again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(x-a)^2+y^2=a^2\ \ast$ so that center is $C=(a,0)$

Hence line is $x-a=-2y$ so that we plug it in $\ast$

We have $y= \pm \frac{a}{\sqrt{5}}$ which plays a role of height and which is $y$-coordinate of
intersection points $A,\ B$

So \begin{align*}{\rm Area}\ \Delta AOB &={\rm Area}\ \Delta AOC + {\rm Area}\ \Delta OCB\\&= \frac{a}{\sqrt{5}}\cdot a\end{align*}