# Two circles meet at $A$ (and $B$), and their common tangents meet at $O$. Show that $\overline{OA}$ bisects the angle made by the two tangents at $A$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, tangent-line, geometric-transformation

> Two circles are cut at $A$ and $B$, and their common tangents meet at $O$. If $AP$ and $AQ$ are the tangents at $A$ to the circles, how do you prove that $OA$ bisects $\angle PAQ$?

I have tried using the properties of circle that I knew of. I had a thought of orthogonal circles but couldn't proceed with it. Though I have been unable to bring coordinate geometry into picture, but I didn't get any clue of it.

Comment: As I mentioned to you in [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3236579/409), isolated problem statements are discouraged here. To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3273685/edit) to say something of what you know about the problem and/or where you got stuck. (Before, you asked a question that involved techniques you had not yet covered in class. Could that be the case here?)

Comment: @Blue That is not the case here. But I have tried everything I knew of but am unable to prove it.

Comment: @Aditya Jain I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thanks for giving your time. Can you give me a small hint on to start this question.

Comment: @AdityaJain: You should show "everything" you've tried, so that people don't waste time duplicating your effort or telling you things you already know. Also: Your previous questions have involved coordinate geometry; are you looking for a coordinate-based solution to this problem? The more you can say about the problem or its context, the better. *Help us help you.*

Comment: I have tried using the properties of circle that I knew of. I had a thought of orthogonal circles but couldn't proceed with it. Though I have been unable to bring coordinate geometry into picture, a solution of that kid will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ be our circles, $OA\cap\Phi_1=\{A,B\}$ and $OA\cap\Phi_2=\{A,C\}.$

We'll assume that $A$ placed between $B$ and $C$ and $B$ placed between $A$ and $O$.

Thus, $O$ is a center of a homotety $h$, for which $h(\Phi_1)=\Phi_2.$

Now, let $l_1$ and $l_2$ be tangents to $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ respectively such that $l_1\cap l_2=\{A\}$.

Since $h(A)=C$, we obtain $h(l_1)||l_1$ and $h(l_1)$ is a tangent line to $\Phi_2$.

Now, let $l_2\cap h(l_1)=\{D\}$.

Thus, $DC=DA$, $\measuredangle DCA=\measuredangle DAC$ and we are done!

Comment: You don't have tag geometric transformations yet.